# Playback for a PSF file

Tags: video, file-format

Note: This question was previously on serverfault.com and found out that was the wrong place for it so I moved it and the answer to here.

I downloaded some footage from my apartment buildings security camera but I can't open/view it.

It's a 13mb PSF file and a 30kb PST file.

Any idea how I can open / convert this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a thumb drive to get the files off of the recording box. Because I'm on a mac I didn't notice it at first but the system puts an exe (windows) file on the drive that act as the video player. Using that video player you can see the video just fine.

** EDIT **

After doing a bit more research I found out that PSF stands for *Progressive Segmented Frames* and the program used on windows is called "VMax ACS" and I'm currently downloading a version of it for mac. The download links are:

*CAUTION:* If these links are dead / bad then just google for the software and you'll be able to find a link.

[VMax ACS Playback for Windows](http://dw-vmax.soft112.com/)

[VMax ACS Playback for Mac OSX 10.6+ 64-bit only](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dw-acs/id510305616?mt=12)

PS The mac version *cannot* open files from a resource, it can only view live footage.